# UWP: Error in Windows Runtime metadata validation

Tags: uwp, metadata, wack

I have a C# app targeting Windows-10 desktop platform.
I am trying to run WACK test for my app & I am seeing this error:

1. FAILED Type location

Error Found: The type location test detected the following errors:

- The types in the Windows.ApplicationModel namespace are located in
  file Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd that does not
  match the namespace.

2. FAILED Type name correctness

Error Found: The type name correctness test detected the following errors:

- The Windows.ApplicationModel.AddResourcePackageOptions type in the
  Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd file is in the Windows
  namespace.

3. FAILED General metadata correctness

Error Found: The general metadata correctness test detected the following errors:

- The type
  Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.IConnectedAnimationConfiguration in
  file Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd has the same GUID
  as the following types:
  Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.IConnectedAnimationConfiguration. All
  GUIDs must be unique.

Comment: Is your app a desktop application using desktop bridge or a UWP application?  The Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace is not supported in Windows desktop applications that use the Desktop Bridge

Comment: My app is a uwp. In my app I used a class from the file Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd. When the release is built, the file Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd is automatically packed. and Then the packet fails Windows certification test

Comment: The problem has been solved. The reason is that a property "ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path" referenced from the file "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd" is used in a library project not related to UI.